# How do I get all users information(name,email...etc) from FB apps?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I want to get all users information from my FB apps,

I tried Graph API and got only the information of my app.

Is there any way to get the users information by Graph API or something else?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

You need to authorize the user first, which is explained very well in the Facebook docs (including example code): https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/v2.1

To get the basic user information, just use the `/me` endpoint. What you get is explained in the docs: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.1/user

For other information, you need different permissions and different endpoints.

Comment: I did that and I can get the information by Graph API by id, but I want to know is there any way to get all users information by json once,Thanks for your answer.

Comment: Not really sure what you’re asking here – but you can specify the fields you want, and even “nest” API calls, see https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/using-graph-api/v2.1#fieldexpansion

Comment: I made a FB App,and I want to get all the users information at once.I can now only get their information by their ID, something like GET graph.facebook.com/{users-id}

Comment: don´t use the id, just use /me - which points to the authorized user. and please specify what information you want to get exactly. /me offers some basic stuff like email (with the correct permission), name, ...